# Converting multiple minutes digits (more than 2) minutes to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, nsregularexpression

I am trying to parse a clock string composed by a multiple number of minutes and convert it to a `NSDate` using a `NSDateFormatter`.

An example of the string I am trying to parse is `@"1234:56"`, where 1234 are the minutes of the clock and 56 the seconds. I tried to use a format such as `@"mmmm:ss"` but it returned nil.

In case it is possible, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: there is no format such as "mmmm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the thing that you want to do, but I suggest do something like that:

```
NSArray *timeArray = [@"1234:56" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSUInteger minutes = [[timeArray firstObject] integerValue];
NSUInteger seconds = [[timeArray lastObject] integerValue];

NSTimeInterval totalSeconds = minutes*60+seconds;
```

And then you should create a new date object and work with this.

```
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:totalSeconds];
```

Comment: Thanks man. I guess that only paying attention on the clock time (and ignoring day, month and years) I will be able to parse it properly.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` only works with legal date format and there is no 'mmmm'.You should get date by yourself:

```
NSString *str = @"234:56";
NSArray<NSString *> *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger minute = 0;
NSInteger second = 0;
switch (components.count) {
    case 1:
        second = components[0].integerValue;
        break;
    case 2:
        second = components[0].integerValue;
        minute = components[1].integerValue;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
// then convert to hours.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
self.timerLabel.text = timeString;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert that to HH:mm:ss then my approach will be something like:

```
// assuming you wouldn't have any hours in the string and format will always be minutes:seconds 

 NSArray *timeArray = [@"1234:56" componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; 

 //array's firstObject will be the "minutes/Hours"
 NSString *minutesAndHours = [timeArray firstObject];
 int hours = [minutesAndHours intValue]/60;
 int minutes = [minutesAndHours intValue]%60;
 int seconds = [timeArray lastObject];

//create the format

NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",hours,minutes,seconds];

//then use the time format
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",hours,minutes,seconds];
NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:time];
```

something like this